# Как исключить трассировку Fast Report в Делфи?

Tags: delphi, отладка, fastreport

Как из трассировки исключить трассировку модулей Fast Report (frx*.pas)?
А то их трассировка занимает больше времени, нежели трассировка самого проекта.

Comment: 1. Не входить в них (F8 вместо F7) :) 2. Исключить из BrowsingPath и LibraryPath опций Delphi пути к исходникам FastReport (в LibraryPath должны быть пути к dcu).

Comment: Можно ставить брейк пойнты - и потом при входе в Fast Report F9

Comment: @kami, как-то с путями не сильно понятно.

Comment: @AlbertFomin - огромное спасибо. И чего я раньше их не применял, не знаю. И правда удобно.

Comment: В опциях Delphi и опциях проекта есть 2 поля: LibraryPath и BrowsingPath. При компиляции они миксуются попарно. LibraryPath используется для сборки, чаще всего там указывают путь к dcu компонентов, дабы не пересобирать их каждый раз. BrowsingPath используется для трассировки - если в BrowsingPath есть путь к модулю, в класс и метод из модуля можно зайти по F7. Иначе - нельзя. Поэтому я и посоветовал исключить из BrowsingPath пути к FastReport, а в LibraryPath убедиться, что используется путь к dcu-папке FRX.

Comment: @I_CaR Для брекпойнтов также можно задавать условие. Например, в цикле, чтобы остановилось на 1971 элементе, ставим i=1971. Ctrl+Alt+B список брекпойнтов, Ctrl + E редактирование, можно там условие задать.

Comment: @kami, в опциях проекта нашёл лишь `Search path`. В опциях Delphi удалял путь из `Library Path` (в `Browsing Path` пути к Fast Report у меня нет) и это стало вызывать ошибку Fatal Error - File not Found frx*.dcu.

Answer (score 3):

Нужно перекомпилировать исходники FastReport без отладочной информации.

Запускаем `Recompile Wizard` из комплекта поставки, **снимаем чекбокс** `With debug info` и компилим.

[image: FastReport Recompile Wizard]

Comment: Странно, но эта рекомпиляция не помогла.

Comment: Проверьте в опциях Delphi и опциях проекта поля: LibraryPath и BrowsingPath. Туда ли компилится FastReport?